# xpath output including "String="

Tags: xml, xpath

I've been battling trying to extract values from a node name and attribute value using xpath with xml. I've searched on this many times but not found anything about my particular issue of String= being part of the returned output.

I thought I had the syntax correct, but somehow while trying to extract values through xpath I am getting String='value' instead of just value.

When I try

```
string(/Data/child::object1/string(@display_value))
```

The output is `String='482899'` whereas I had hoped for `482899` (or `'482899'`). Similarly with this:

```
name(/Data/child::object1)
```

That's return `String='object1'`.

The XML I am working with is static (I cannot edit its format, which is part of why I have such tortured xpath). Below is a partial sample of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data>
    <object1 display_value="482899" />
    <object2 display_value="61317 " />
</Data>
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: `string` just shows the type of output. How do you run your code? I am sure you can turn off the output type in your program.

Comment: Floo0 and kjhughes are right -- `String=` is not coming from the XPath. It's coming from the environment (e.g. programming language) that you're evaluating the XPath with. Tell us about that environment and someone can doubtless help you fix it.

Answer (score 2):

`String=` is not part of what XPath itself is selecting.  Rather, it's just the user interface to the particular XPath library you're using trying to be helpful in identifying that you've selected a string as opposed to an element, attribute, etc.